# How to change character set in Oracle 11g r2 Express edition

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have to change the character set from AL32UTF8 to WE8MSWIN1252 in a Oracle 11g r2 Express instance... I tried to use the command:

```
ALTER DATABASE CHARACTER SET WE8MSWIN1252;
```

But it fails saying that MSWIN1252 isn't a superset of AL32UTF8. Then I found some articles talking about CSSCAN, and that tool doesn't seem to be available in Oracle 11 Express.

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/CharacterSetMigration.php

Anyone has an idea on how to do that? Thanks in advance

**Edit**
Clarifying a little bit: The real issue is that I'm trying to import data into a table that has a column defined as VARCHAR(6 byte). The string causing the issue is 'eq.mês', it needs 6 bytes in MSWIN1252 and 7 bytes in UT8

Comment: whats wrong with UTF8?  if you need extra space to hold some characters, simply increase the field's length.

Comment: I'd like to keep database DDL identical in both instances... I'm thinking about changing the column to VARCHAR(6 CHARACTER) but I don't know if there are any downsides on this

Comment: that sounds like a reasonable plan to me (more so than changing charsets)

Comment: If you care that much about the character set than you probably shouldn't be using Express Edition.  Express Edition is good for students and a few rare training and production uses.  But based on the [OTN developer license](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/standard-license-152015.html), most people using Express Edition can freely use Enterprise Edition instead.  Or in the worst case, pay a few hundred bucks for Personal Edition.

Comment: Check character sets supported by oracle express edition at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18803/toc.htm#BABBBIBE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.

The Express Edition of 11g is only available using a UTF-8 character set.  If you want to go back to the express edition of 10g, there was a Western European version that used the Windows-1252 character set.  Unlike with the other editions, Oracle doesn't support the full range of character sets in the Express Edition nor does it support changing the character set of an existing XE database.

Why do you believe you need to change the database character set?  Other than potentially taking a bit more storage space to support the characters in the upper half of the Windows-1252 range, which generally aren't particularly heavily used, there aren't many downsides to a UTF-8 database.

Comment: I have an existing database in production... It runs on a full Oracle 11g instance using WE8MSWIN1252. I need to import it on this Oracle Express instance

Comment: @alessandroasm - And you're running into space issues?  You should be able to declare the column as `VARCHAR2(6 CHAR)` to allocate 6 characters rather than 6 bytes or set the `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` to "CHAR" so that a `VARCHAR2(6)` allocates 6 characters rather than 6 bytes.  Or you could just increase the size of all the character columns that store non-ASCII data.

Comment: I found out that Oracle Express DOES support WE8MSWIN1252... All I had to do was to run 

`createDb -dbchar WE8MSWIN1252`

Comment: @alessandroasm - You can, but it's not something I'd suggest.  Oracle explicitly tried to limit the set of available character sets for XE databases so it is entirely possible that you'll break something by trying to work around that or that some future update or script will assume that the database character set is UTF-8 and will cause issues in your database.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that your best option when you want to go to a character set that supports only a subset of the original characters, that your best option is to use exp and imp back (or expdp and impdp).

Are you sure that no single table will contain any character not found in the 1252 code page ?

Comment: That is expdp, re-create entire database, and impdp back.

Comment: The real issue is that I'm trying to import data into a table that has a column defined as VARCHAR(6 byte). And then there's one row that has exactly 6 bytes on the source encoding but needs 7 on the destination one...

Comment: Not possible. Every character takes one byte in MSWIN1252, and no character takes half a byte in UTF-8.

Comment: Not possible when considering english characters... the string causing the issue is 'eq.mês'

Comment: That's 6 bytes in MSWIN1252 and 7 in UTF8. It is not possible that you can have this in a field if the field is defined as `VARCHAR2(6 BYTE)` and the character set is UTF8.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of only execute that ALTER DATABASE command is that the Data Dictionary was not converted and it can be corrupted.

I had the same problem. In my case, we are using a Oracle 11g Express Edition (11.2.0.2.0) and we really need that it runs on WE8MSWIN1252 character set, but I cannot change the character set on installation (it always install with AL32UTF8).

With a Oracle Client 11g installed as Administrator and run only the `csscan full=y` (check this link https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/character-set-migration) and we notice that are lossy and convertible data problems in our database. But, the problems are with the MDSYS (Oracle Spatial) and APEX_040000 (Oracle Application Express) schemas. So, as we dont need this products, we remove them (check this link: http://fast-dba.blogspot.com.br/2014/04/how-to-remove-unwanted-components-from.html).

Then, we export with `expdp` the users schemas and drop the users (they must be recreated at the end of the process).

Executing csscan again with `full=y capture=y`, it reports that: `The data dictionary can be safely migrated using the CSALTER script`. If the report doesnt have this, the csalter.plb script will not work, because there are some conditions that will not be satisfied:

- changeless for all CHAR VARCHAR2, and LONG data (Data Dictionary and Application Data)
- changeless for all Application Data CLOB
- changeless and/or convertible for all Data Dictionary CLOB

In our case, this conditions were satisfied and we could ran the CSALTER script successfully. Moreover, this script executes the ALTER DATABASE command you are trying to run and it converts the CLOB data of Data Dictionary that is convertible.

Finally, we create the users and the tablespaces of our application and we import the dump of the user data successfully.